# Apple Wallet Animation for Android

Tags: android, animation, wallet, cardview

I am in search of apple wallet kind of animation for android. Can you please help me out of this.
Link 1 : https://github.com/3lvis/CardStack
Link 2 : https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3096

These are points I am looking out in this animation module

1. First screen would be the cardstack
2. Once I click on any card , It should be opened up to a detailed card screen with some pop effect as in iOS
3. Next card can be viewed from there itself by swiping the view to right or left
4. When card dragged to below it should again come to the stack
5. If dragged Up/Right/Left it should be dragged back to its position

Comment: You linked an Android library that does something like this, so take the library and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Already did that but the library has its limitations. I have mentioned 5 points which are very much required for it . I have done 1st and 3rd point in my sample project rest are pending please help me out to achieve that

Comment: I don't see how I can help, I can't implement those features for you.

Comment: I found two repositories which implements this:  [CardStackUI](https://github.com/mutualmobile/CardStackUI), [CardStackView](https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView)